# Java Errors Illegal Start of Expression

Tags: java

I'm getting errors that this has an illegal start of expression and it shows just about every line as being a problem. Any help with what I'm missing here?

```
public abstract class Shapes
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    protected final double pi=3.14;

    //varible pi is delcared as constant

     protected double radius;
     protected double height;

     public Shapes (double gRadius,double gHeight)  
     {
        //sets radius, height variables to parameter values
        radius=gRadius;
        height=gHeight;
     }

          abstract public double getCircumference();
          abstract public double getTotalSurfaceArea();
          abstract public double getVolume();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you put the contents of your class inside your main method.

Just move your main :

```
public abstract class Shapes
{
    protected final double pi=3.14;

    //varible pi is delcared as constant

     protected double radius;
     protected double height;

     public Shapes (double gRadius,double gHeight)  
     {
        //sets radius, height variables to parameter values
        radius=gRadius;
        height=gHeight;
     }

     abstract public double getCircumference();
     abstract public double getTotalSurfaceArea();
     abstract public double getVolume();

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: @Rustam I meant that all the contents of the class were inside the main method.

Answer (score 0):

**Variable**, **methods** and **constructor** must be declared inside the **Class** for which class you are declaring them, not inside the **main** method so move all your **Variable**, **methods** and **constructor** declaration inside the class from main method, then your code will be working fine.!

```
public abstract class Shapes{

protected final double pi=3.14;

//varible pi is delcared as constant

 protected double radius;
 protected double height;

 public Shapes (double gRadius,double gHeight)  
 {
    //sets radius, height variables to parameter values
    radius=gRadius;
    height=gHeight;
 }

 abstract public double getCircumference();
 abstract public double getTotalSurfaceArea();
 abstract public double getVolume();

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all variable, method inside class only.and all the object creation and invoking method must be do in main() method.like this
     public abstract class Shapes
{
    protected final double pi=3.14;

```
 protected double radius;
 protected double height;

 public Shapes (double gRadius,double gHeight)  
 {
    //sets radius, height variables to parameter values
    radius=gRadius;
    height=gHeight;
 }

 abstract public double getCircumference();
 abstract public double getTotalSurfaceArea();
 abstract public double getVolume();
public static void main(String args[])
{
} 
}
```